# Refreshing a div, rather than page after clicking submit button using AJAX

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

I have a table populated by a SQL database. The table is hidden until a search button is clicked to return the results.

I'm trying to use ajax to refresh the table, rather than the page. If the page refreshes, the class on the table returns making it hidden again so the content of the table only appears briefly.

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchForm').on('submit', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Index',
            data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $("#resultsTable").removeClass("d-none");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Form:

```
<form asp-page="./Index" id="searchForm" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by name:
            <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" id="searchName" />

            @*<a asp-page="./Index">Back to full List</a>*@
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

The code above runs and executes fine but the page still refreshes. I suspect I've missed something.

Comment: place an `e` parameter on on submit event, and call `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

use `e.preventDefault()`

```
 $(function () {
        $('#searchForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Index',
                data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $("#resultsTable").removeClass("d-none");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: did u add `e` in function parameter?

Comment: should be `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks, I was using preventDefault() except it doesn't pass the search string and only returns all of the results, how to I pass that in?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your query

Comment: If I'm right your `$('#searchForm').serialize()` does not contain `search string`.Right?

Comment: The button is for a search form, if I search for anything now it returns all of the results, rather than the filtered results.

Comment: Yes, quite right, how do I pass in the search string?

Comment: Please console.log `$('#searchForm').serialize()` and see whether your search string is there and let me know.

Comment: It appears the search string is there, SearchString=wendy is logged. When I search a name.

Comment: Then it might be ur backend logic issue.Log in your `Index` file and see whether filtering works fine or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190625/discussion-between-m14-and-fullerprime).

Answer (score 0):

use [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be. The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event listeners calls stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation(), either of which terminates propagation at once.

```
<input id="search" type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />

$(function () {
$('#searchForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const search = $('#search').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Index',
        data: { search },
        success: function () {
            $("#resultsTable").removeClass("d-none");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Then in your PHP

```
<?php searchValue = $_GET['search']; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using preventDefault() except it doesn't pass the search string and only returns all of the results, how to I pass that in?

Comment: I've added the form to the question.

Comment: @FullerPrime see my updated answer, add an `id` to your input.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET, when searching it directs to the URL /?SearchString=searchterm, I think this may be where it's not working. Do I need to update the URL to in the Ajax call? The search bar and table are both on the index page.